# Google analytics counting two times Iframe content from another website

Tags: asp.net, iframe, google-analytics

we have two websites  and on website one (1) we are displaying the  content from website two (2) by using Iframe. Everything is working fine but  the problem is google analytics  showing two hits because of the content coming from second website. HOw can I display my content on my site(1) that google analytics only count one time.
I do not have the access to the website1 content except i used Iframe to display the contetnt on website 1.
IS there any possibility to display content without Iframe while do not have direct access to the content of the other website.

Comment: If 2 web pages trigger the analytics code then you get 2 hits. Can't you remove one of the pageview triggering code ?

Comment: Here is the scenario. i have a website which partial content of the page. (just say content slider of my page) is displaying in my sister company website by using Iframe as they do not have rights to use my code or access my website through server. so when someone hit their website page that contain my website partial content through iframe my site also get the google hit becuase they are accessing my website page through iframe. so what technique should i use that it will not count in gooogle analytics.

Comment: Can someone help me for this issue.